# How can i create one form who contains multiple forms as fields using collectionType in symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I want to create multiples forms in one page with one submit buttons with symfony. I checked the documentation and i saw i will need to make a form with a collectiontype field but i don't know how to proceed. I have two forms in two page, the first page the user tell how many forms the next page will have . I already create my first form and its working fine, i have the data of the first form but now how i can create the second page that contain multiple forms depending of the submited data. 
Here is my first form :

```
class OrdersType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add ('tickets', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => TicketsType::class,
                'allow_add' => true
            ])
            ->add('numberOfTickets', ChoiceType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ],
                'choices' => [
                    '1' => 1,
                    '2' => 2,
                    '3' => 3,
                    '4' => 4,
                    '5' => 5,
                ]
            ])
            ->add('date', DateType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ],
                'widget' => 'single_text'
            ])
            ->add('type', ChoiceTYpe::class, [
            'attr' => [
            'class' => 'form-control'
            ],
            'choices' => [
            'Journée' => 1,
            'Demi-journée(à partir de 14 heures)' => 0,
        ]
    ])
        ;
    }

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Orders::class,
    ]);
}
}
```

And my second form (the one i want to duplicate in my second page) :

```
class TicketsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('category', CheckboxType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('lastname', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('country', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('dateOfBirth', DateType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ],
                'widget' => 'single_text'
            ])
        ;
    }

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Tickets::class,
    ]);
}
}
```

and my controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="home")
 */
public function home(Request $request, SessionInterface $session)
{
    $Orders = new Orders();
    $form = $this->createForm(OrdersType::class, $Orders);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted()){
        $formData = $form->getData();
        $session->set('orders', $formData);
        return $this->redirectToRoute('ticket');
        }


    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Tickets::class);
    $tickets = $repo->findAll();
    return $this->render('louvre/home.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);

}

/**
 * @Route("/ticket", name="ticket")
 */
public function ticket(Request $request, SessionInterface $session)
{
    $data = $session->get('orders');
    $Orders = new Orders()
    for ($i=0; $i<$data->getNumberOfTickets() ;$i++){
    echo 'test';
    $tickets = new Tickets();;
    $form = $this->createForm(OrdersType::class, $Orders);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    };
    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Tickets::class);
    $tickets = $repo->findAll();
    return $this->render('louvre/ticket.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: you wrote: "create multiples forms in one page with one submit button".  I think if there are only one submit button, you have to consider that it is one form not multiples

Comment: Have a look a craue/form-flow-bundle. It offfers exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes i already know i need to create one form but this form contains multiple forms as fields . @mblaettermann ok i will take a look at this thank you, i will tell you if its good after.

Comment: @mblaettermann I checked craue form flow that looks very good, but i see it needs only one template to render alls the forms, but i need differents css stylesheets for my differents steps, is it possible to do that with craue form flow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to make the `CollectionType` not in my form but in my controller, so I deleted:

```
->add(
    'tickets',
    CollectionType::class,
    [
        'entry_type' => TicketsType::class,
        'allow_add' => true
    ]
)
```

Then when I want to make a `CollectionType` of my form I write this in my controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    CollectionType::class,
    $tickets,
    ['entry_type' => TicketsType::class]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from symfony 3.4 that shows two different forms on the same page with a single submit button. Note that the head of household is a Member entity and the household is a Household entity:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(HouseholdType::class, $household);
    $formHead = $this->createForm(MemberType::class, $head);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $formHead->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() && $formHead->isSubmitted() && $formHead->isValid()) {
        //relevant logic 
    }

    return $this->render(
            'Household/new.html.twig',
            array(
                'formType' => 'New Household',
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'formHead' => $formHead->createView(),
                'title' => 'New Household',
            )
    );
```

Comment: I want to create one form who contain multiple form not to create multiple forms.

Comment: So you might want to edit your question where it says, "I want to create multiples forms in one page with one submit buttons". My answer shows how one might have two forms on one page with one submit button. From a user's perspective that solution appears to be one form with one submit button.

Comment: Ok, i edited my title, but do you know how i can create multiples forms as fields using collection type in symfony 4 ? you can read my topic for more details.

Comment: I suggest you start with [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).

Comment: I already read this documentation before i asked for help. I don't know how can i apply this with my two forms.

Comment: The form TicketsType looks to contain fields relating only to a person (fields for name, etc). So if the OrdersType form embeds a Collection field type for Tickets this says that a single Order has many persons (Tickets). Is this your intention? It might help if you could clarify your use case.

Comment: yes an order have one or more tickets (up to 5) and one ticket have only one order. I did two entity and already have a relation .